# VBA Obtener fragmento de texto de un elemento html con id

Tags: excel, vba, macros, get

Estoy tratando de acceder a una pagina web con una macro en Excel, introducir un código en un input, pulsar un botón y copiar el precio resultante de la búsqueda. Es este ultimo paso el que no logro. El elemento que contiene el precio tiene el id #result_ok pero uno de los inconvenientes es que es un nodo de texto que no acaba de estar dentro de nada y a la vez tiene tres  hermanos. Os lo muestro:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He tratado de hacer un getElementById y acceder a su innerText o innerHTML y nada... Obtiene código que no corresponde a su texto interior o varios errores al intentar otras cosas.

```
Sub buscar()

Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Dim DOC As HTMLDocument
Dim url As String

Set IE = Nothing
Set DOC = Nothing

url = "http://www.salvadorescoda.com/tarifas/index.htm"
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate url

While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Wend

Set DOC = IE.document.frames


Dim iFrameDoc As HTMLDocument

Set iFrameDoc = DOC.Item("mainFrame").document 'especificamos el nombre del frame
If iFrameDoc Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "No existe ningún frame con el nombre especificado."
    IE.Quit
    Set IE = Nothing
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim itemEle As Object

'ya estamos en el frame, ahora podemos conseguir el elemento INPUT
For Each itemEle In iFrameDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
    If itemEle.getAttribute("class") = "campocodigo" Then
        itemEle.Value = ActiveCell.Value
        Exit For
    End If
Next

'buscamos y clickamos el botón buscar
For Each itemEle In iFrameDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
    If itemEle.getAttribute("class") = "floatright botonbuscar" Then
        itemEle.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next

'¿Como obtengo el texto?
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = iFrameDoc.getElementsById("result_ok").innerHTML




'IE.Quit
'Set IE = Nothing


End Sub
```

Sabéis cual es el problema? Como puedo obtenerlo? Muchas gracias por adelantado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¡Hola!

Es lo mismo de siempre. Se trata de hacer un bucle con todos los elementos DIV que tengas, hasta identificar el que te interesa.

Yo he añadido al código, después de la parte donde haces click en buscar, lo siguiente:

```
Dim EsteDiv As HTMLDivElement 'variable para encontrar el elemento DIV que nos interesa

Dim EsteString() As String 'Matriz tipo STRING para almacenar el texto que nos interesa del DIV

'Nuevo bucle para coneguir el DIV de resultados
For Each EsteDiv In iFrameDoc.getElementsByTagName("div")
    If EsteDiv.getAttribute("id") = "result_ok" Then
    'estamos en el DIV que interesa. Cogemos todo el texto y lo dividimos con SPLIT
    'usando como delimitador 1 espacio en blanco
    'Así creamos una matrix de Texto con varios valores, pero el precio siempre estará en el último Index de la matriz
    'el último Index siempre se saca con UBOUND
        EsteString = Split(EsteDiv.textContent, " ")
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = EsteString(UBound(EsteString))
        Exit For
    End If
Next EsteDiv

Set EsteDiv = Nothing
```

Por resumir el proceso, lo que hago es que divido el texto entero del DIV, usando como carácter delimitador el espacio. En tu ejemplo, el texto entero del DIV es algo así:

`Artículo:  AA02079Descripción: V.ASIENTO JENKINS 2 1/2"PVP (Sin IVA): 379.82€`

De todo el texto, solamente me interesa lo último. Todo lo demás me sobra. Entonces lo que hago es que divido la cadena, usando la función **[Split (más info aquí)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/split-function)**

Esto me devuelve una matriz de varios valores (en este caso hasta 10, porque el valor inicial en una matriz siempre está en el index 0), que son los siguientes:

1. Matriz(0) = Artículo:
2. Matriz(1) =
3. Matriz(2) = AA02079Descripción:
4. Matriz(3) = V.ASIENTO
5. Matriz(4) = JENKINS
6. Matriz(5) = 2
7. Matriz(6) = 1/2"PVP
8. Matriz(7) = (Sin
9. Matriz(8) = IVA):
10. Matriz(9) = 379.82€

De todos, nos interesa el último, que es el precio. Nos interesa Matriz(9). Y hemos tenido suerte porque, tal cual está diseñada la web ahora mismo, **siempre nos va a interesar el último valor** porque es el precio.

Para saber el último valor dentro de una matriz, usamos la propiedad **[Ubound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/ubound-function)**

Y para llamar a un valor concreto de una matriz, es simplemente usar un número. Es decir, si escribes, por ejemplo, `Activecell.Value = Matriz(3)` obtendrás el cuarto valor. Pero si escribes `ActiveCell.Value = Matriz (Ubound(Matriz))` siempre obtendrás el último valor de la matriz, independientemente de su tamaño.

Así que con todas estas ideas es como he diseñado el código, y esto es lo que yo obtengo tras ejecutarlo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que te sirva, y puedas adaptar el código a tus necesidades.

Comment: También comentarte que con VBA puedes ejecutar funciones en JavaScript. Viendo el código fuente de la página, me parece que el precio se devuelve usando una función en Javascript, que devuelve la información según el valor introducido en búsqueda. Pero desconozco cómo hacerlo. Pero si lo investigas y lo consigues, seguramente sea más rápido que con webscrapping como estamos haciendo. Puedes ver el código aquí: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Kdde.jpg A ver si te sirve